# SQL - replacing placeholder with parameter values

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin

I have a function that generates an SQL string. The query works fine and I fetch the data I need. The issue I have is that I am building a query as a string which is vulnerable to an SQL injection attacks. I passing `uuids` as a parameter in an example below, but not tuples. For tuples I am just building a string input. It looks like this:

```
private fun generateSQLForTuples(tuplesList: List<List<String>>):String =
    """
      select id, subcustomer
      from customer
      where uuid = any(:uuids)
      union
      select id, subcustomer
      from customer
      where (customer_id, subcustomer) in (${toJdbcTuples(tuplesList)})
    """.trimIndent()
```

Since, I didn't find the right jdbc data type for tuples I am generating a string and passing it directly with `toJdbcTuples(tuplesList)` function. Now, since I would like to have some kind of protection from SQL injection attacks, I thought of creating first a list of placeholders for tuples that would look like this:

```
((?, ?), (?, ?))
```

And then I would create a list to match the placeholder. This is the code where I create placeholders and tuples:

```
val placeholdersForTuples = customers.map { listOf("?", "?") }
val tuples = customers.map { listOf(it["customerId"] as String, it["subCustomer"] as String) }
val existingCustomers = fetchRows(
      ctx, generateSQLForTuples(placeholdersForTuples), mapOf("uuids" to customers.map { it["uuid"] })
  )
```

But, I am not sure how should I then pass the list with actual tuple values as a parameter into a prepared statement with placeholders?
I am already passing a named parameter `uuids` to `fetchRows` function for an `SQL` that is generated with `generateSQLForTuples(tuples)`. How can I do that for tuples placeholders as well?

Comment: Looks like search for "Row value expression". Here example for [jOOQ  - Tuples or row value expressions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/row-value-expressions/) and [jOOQ and Kotlin](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-kotlin/)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without jOOQ @LukaszSzozda?

Comment: if it were a simple query such as `select * from t where str = ?` how do you provide the value for the placeholder?

Answer (score 2):

Tuples expects to work with Object[], so for it to work with a List it should be a List<Object[]>.

```
val tuples = java.util.List.of(arrayOf<Any>("AAA", 111, 'X'), arrayOf<Any>("BBB", 222, 'Y'))


 val sql = ("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE "
            + "WHERE (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) "
            + "IN (:values)") // <-- the placeholder


    val list: Unit = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
        sql,
        MapSqlParameterSource() // bind the list to the placeholder
            .addValue("values", tuples)
    )
```

courtesy: [Alessandro](https://alessandrococco.com/2020/12/how-to-pass-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-in-clause-using-namedparameterjdbctemplate)

Comment: I have tried to translate that to Kotlin, but didn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be passing multiple input tuples as JSON(string argument) and using `JSON_TO_RECORDSET` to parse it back at SQL side:

```
SELECT s.customer_id, s.subcustomer
FROM json_to_recordset('[{"customer_id":1, "subcustomer":"a"},{"customer_id":3, "subcustomer":"c"}]'::json) 
     AS s(customer_id INT, subcustomer TEXT);
```

Full demo:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE (customer_id, subcustomer) in 
   (SELECT s.customer_id, s.subcustomer 
    FROM json_to_recordset('[{"customer_id":1, "subcustomer":"a"},{"customer_id":3, "subcustomer":"c"}]'::json) AS s(customer_id INT, subcustomer TEXT)
   )
```

The input: `'[{"customer_id":1, "subcustomer":"a"},{"customer_id":3, "subcustomer":"c"}]'` should be constructed on the application side

**[db<fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=42b7160023c4539c61364101ed9d885d)**

Comment: But my query is already working and that is fine. The question is about how to pass the values on the application side as a parameter to a prepared statement?

Comment: Is that a SQL injection attack waiting to happen?

Comment: @RobertPerry Why? If the parameter is provided as binded value(string argument)? `SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE (customer_id, subcustomer) in 
   (SELECT s.customer_id, s.subcustomer 
    FROM json_to_recordset(?::json) AS s(customer_id INT, subcustomer TEXT)
   )`